# AngularUI Button color changes onclick

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get certain buttons when selected to change from btn btn-default to btn btn-primary with angularui. I tried getting it working like this

```
$('#uploadButton').click(function() {
 $('#uploadButton').removeClass("btn btn-default");
        $('#uploadButton').addClass("btn btn-primary");
 }
```

but it's no good. Can someone demonstrate to me how to do this with AngularUI?

Comment: do you just want the button to change while it's being clicked? If so, you might be able to do this with just some css: `btn:active { ... }`

Comment: I want it to be white when not selected and blue when selected. And I tried this but it didn't work btn:active { background-color:blue; }

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the [ngClass directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass).  Since you are only toggling classes, you do not need anything specific to AngularUI to achieve the effect you want.

Let's say that in your controller you have a value that indicates whether the button is toggled active and a function to toggle the value.  It might look something like:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.isActive = false;

  $scope.toggleActive = function() {
    $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive;
  };
});
```

You can then use the `isActive` variable with the ngClass directive in your markup to make decisions about which class to use:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" ng-class="{true: 'btn-primary', false: 'btn-default'}[isActive]" ng-click="toggleActive()">Upload</button>
```

In this case, the button will have the class `btn-primary` when `isActive` is true, and `btn-default` when it is false.  Clicking the button will call the toggle function, which will update the active value and cause the class to update.  Since `btn` should always be applied, it is removed from the logic and simply put in a class attribute.

This approach has the added benefit of keeping your CSS classes out of your controller logic.  IMO, this ultimately makes the controller tests less brittle and the view more flexible.

You can see it in action on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jKmxJwDnkuxpgy7zYyx6?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .directive('bootstrapBtn', bootstrapBtn);

  function bootstrapBtn() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      template: '<button type="button" ng-class="test" class="btn" ng-click="add(1)">{{color}}</button>',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

        scope.counter = 0;
        scope.test = "btn-defalult";
        scope.color = "default";

        scope.add = function(inc) {
          scope.counter += inc;
          switch (scope.counter) {
            case 1:
              scope.test = "btn-danger";
              scope.color = "danger";
              break

            case 2:
              scope.test = "btn-success";
              scope.color = "success";
              break

            case 3:
              scope.test = "btn-warning";
              scope.color = "warning";
              break

            case 4:
              scope.test = "btn-info";
              scope.color = "info";
              break

            case 5:
              scope.test = "btn-primary";
              scope.color = "primary";
              break

            default:
              if (scope.counter > 4) {
                scope.test = "btn-defalult";
                scope.color = "default";
                scope.counter = 0;
              }
              break

          }
        };
      }
    }
  };
}());
```

You can write directive like this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VOUrtQy1Ir9ZZM9KOI24)